# ThenInclude in Entity Framework .net core 2.0

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have nested models called `PositionLevel`, `PositionLevelCompanyLookup`, `Company`, `CompanySub`. I want to get all data of the models in the `GetDetail` function with `ThenInclude`. But all data of the model's didn't get and I couldn't see a reason for that.

How do I do that?

```
public class PositionLevel : DynexModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<PositionLevelCompanyLookup> Companies { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual List<Company> CompanyList => this.Companies?.Select(p => p.Company).ToList();
}

public class PositionLevelCompanyLookup : DynexModel
{
    public int PositionLevelId { get; set; }
    public PositionLevel PositionLevel { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Company : DynexModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<CompanySub> SubCompanies { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual List<Company> SubCompanyList => this.SubCompanies?.Select(p => p.SubCompany).ToList();
}

public class CompanySub : DynexModel
{
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; }

        public int SubCompanyId { get; set; }
        public Company SubCompany { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult<PositionLevel> GetDetail(int id)
{
    var res = _context.Entity<PositionLevel>()
             .Include(p => p.Companies)
             .ThenInclude(p => p.Company)
             .ThenInclude(p => p.SubCompanies)
             .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);

    return res ;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're problem there is thne `[NotMapped]` tag on `CompanyList` I think EF is ignoring the main `Include` and with it `ThenInclude` too, try to test it by deleting the `[NotMapped]` tag.

Sorry for my english.